# TypeError: r.details is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a strange problem with a call I'm making to a Factory, where I am populating a form. I'm getting an error "TypeError: r.details is not a function". I have the exact same syntax setup in another call to another service that works just fine. I looked through things to see if there was a typo, but it all looks good.

My Module:

```
var app = angular.module('acnApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
```

My Controller:

```
app.controller('orgUpdateController', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'orgFactory', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, orgFactory) {

//MY CALL. I KNOW THE PARAM IS BEING PASSED AND HAVE CONSOLE.LOGGED IT

$scope.selectedOrg = orgFactory.details({ id: $routeParams.orgId }); }]);
```

My Factory:

```
app.factory('orgFactory', ['$resource','domain', function ($resource,domain) {
return $resource(domain + '/api/networkorg/:id', {}, {
    details: { method: 'GET', params: { id: '@id' }}
});
```

}]);

Running this in Chrome and viewing it in the Console, I get the error:

```
TypeError: r.details is not a function
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:55075/App/angularbundle.min.js:1:3928)
at e (http://localhost:55075/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:96)
at Object.g.instantiate (http://localhost:55075/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:213)
at b.$get (http://localhost:55075/Scripts/angular.min.js:80:257)
at g.link (http://localhost:55075/Scripts/angular-route.min.js:7:268)
at $ (http://localhost:55075/Scripts/angular.min.js:73:46)
at K (http://localhost:55075/Scripts/angular.min.js:61:495)
at g (http://localhost:55075/Scripts/angular.min.js:54:326)
at http://localhost:55075/Scripts/angular.min.js:53:388
at a.$get.h (http://localhost:55075/Scripts/angular.min.js:55:311) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

If anyone sees something wrong, I'd appreciate it!

Thanks.

Comment: what is domain ? is it a factory,service or a simple string

Comment: Hi Maddy, It's a factory calling a web service through $resource. I've actually fixed the problem, though I'm not sure how I did it.